# Can I use the Session Cache service for a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

How can I use the [Bluemix Session Cache service](https://console.stage1.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/session-cache/) with a Node.js application? Can I use data cache for session caching with a Node.js application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is using the express-session module, you can access an early Beta version of a middleware implementation for express session. You can find it on the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sessioncache-express).

If you are not using the express-session module, store the session objects in the data cache using REST API calls and then retrieve the objects manually if the session object does not exist in memory.